# Call jquery function without knowing ID of Text Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My requirement is very clear , I dont want alphabets in my text field but cant change text field to number. By Using following jQuery I have achieved that but problem is i cant assign id in text field. 
  Because in My real code i dont have id so cant use 
  $('#t2').on('keydown keyup', function(e) this code.
  is there any other alternative to call.

Following code is working but cant assign id in real

```
 <!doctype html>
  <head>

    <script 
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
   $(function() {
   var regExp = /[a-z]/i;
   $('#t2').on('keydown keyup', function(e) {
 var value = String.fromCharCode(e.which) || e.key;

  // No letters
  if (regExp.test(value)) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("only nos allowed");
  return false;
   }
   });
   });
      </script>

     <body>
      <form>
      <input type="text" name="t1" id="t2">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `problem is i cant assign id in text field`... but your text field does have an id, doesn't it? `id="t2"`

Comment: $("input").on  ...

Comment: your input has an id.. regardless of type. Type doesn't govern element attributes

Comment: Use name `$('[name="t2"]')`

Comment: Use name $('[name="t1"]')

Comment: You can use any select that identifies the input, it doesn't need to be `#id`, eg, given your html:  `$("input")` or `$("form>input")` or `$("[name=t1]")`

Comment: Neither i have name nor id and i have other input also so cant apply for all input elements

Comment: As you can see from the comments, if you provide working code ("*following code is work*"), people get confused, please provide some code that is **not working and matches your requirements**.

Comment: `$("input:eq(3)")` `$("input").first()`

Comment: From the vote-to-close: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the *shortest code necessary **to reproduce it** in the question itself*. - your code does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Question: if you don't have a name, what are you going to do with the value entered?  How do you reference the value at the moment?

Comment: google jquery selectors and take your pick, there are millions of ways to select an element - especially an input

Answer (score 0):

try to use your textbox like this

```
     <input type="text" name="t1" id="t2" onkeydown="textchange(event)" keyup="textchange(event)" >
function textchange(e){
    var value = String.fromCharCode(e.which) || e.key;
  // No letters
  if (regExp.test(value)) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("only nos allowed");
  return false;
   }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(":input")` to select all input elements or give your input fields common class name and then use `$(".classname")` selector.

For detailed selectors you should check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: But how i will use two selector input and class name

Comment: You don't have to use booth. Just choose one which suits best. But if you want to combine these, solution would be `$(".classname:input")`